# Позиционирование выводимых данных.

Tags: php, html

**Вот код php:**

```
<?php
      session_start();          
    include ("bd.php");
      $result88= mysql_query("SELECT login,avatar,name,number,pole FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4",$db);
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result88);
      $pole=$row['pole'];

       do

                {

           echo "<p><img src=$row[avatar]></p>"."".$row['name']."<br>".$reg."<br>".$row['number']." ";
                }

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result88))
    ?>
```

Его задачей является вывод информации о 4 пользователях и он выводит их следующим образом

```
Картинка1
Логин1
Город1
Номер1

Картинка2
Логин2
Город2
Номер2

Картинка3
Логин3
Город3
Номер3
```

и так далее

Это меня не устраивает
мне необходимо сделать следующее:

```
Картинка1             Картинка2                 Картинка3
Логин1                Логин2                    Логин3
Город1                Город2                    Город3
Номер1                Номер2                    Номер3
```

Помогите)

Comment: Для каждой колонки div враппер со стилем

      display: inline-block; width: 33%; float:left;

Ну а для следующих элементов, если они есть естественно, просто сделайте:


     clear:both;

И будет вам счастье

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте HTML-тег `table`.

---

**UPD:**

```
session_start();
include('bd.php');
$result = mysql_query('SELECT `login`, `avatar`, `name`, `number`, `pole` FROM `users` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4');
echo '<table><tr>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result88)){
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<p><img src="' . $row['avatar'] . '" /></p>' . $row['name'] . '<br>' . $reg . '<br>' . $row['number'];
    echo '</td>';
}
echo '</tr></table>';
```

Comment: @uWeb Как тут его использовать? Покажите пожалуйста на примере!

Comment: @LaKO смотрите ответ еще раз.

Comment: @uWeb вообще этот код работать не будет, но если чуть поправить то все ок. +1

Comment: @LordySL не отрицаю. В чем ошибка-то?

Comment: @uWeb я не про таблицу, а про вывод данных,  вместо ' во надо ")))

Comment: Спасибо помогло)

Comment: @LordySL - внатуре? :D

Comment: @uWeb а как увеличить/уменьшить расстояние между объектами?

Comment: @LaKO в теге прописывай следующее '<td style="250px;">'. Смотря сколько пикселей на столько и будет увеличиваться расстояние!

Comment: @AlexWindHope :D @LaKO читайте, смотрите - [`table`][1]


  [1]: http://htmlbook.ru/html/table

Comment: @AlexWindHope Да да да. Нужно все прописывать так как положено!!!!)

Comment: @LordySL :D